# Import 7,000 images from ipfs link into html

Tags: html, ipfs, webflow

I'm trying to show a gallery of 7,000 images on my Webflow website, but I cannot find a way to import the images over in a way that is effective. I can copy the url for each individual image and paste it into Webflow, but Webflow has a 10,000 character limit on its custom code. This would mean that I'd have to create hundreds of custom code sections in one page to get them all in, as well as spend countless ours manually doing that.

Essentially, I'm trying to find a way to copy an extremely large piece of html (50,000 ish lines of

```
<div>
<img src="image link.png" loading="lazy">
<p class="imgipfs">Name#1</p>
</div>
```

into a webpage that only allows 10,000 characters of code for a custom code import. I've tried to find a way to somehow source this huge chunk of html elsewhere and import that link into the custom code section, but haven't had any luck. I hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know webflow - but I success similar limited project with GTM container.
As you put custom js in google tag manager, the container would load only in the user side - therefore you bypass the limit.